# Item deleting event doesn't get fired when an item in a document library is deleted using retention policy

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-receiver, information-management

I have designed a **custom retention policy** through which items of my document library gets **hard deleted** after a certain amount of days.

After these items are deleted from the document library, I have to update another list as these item status as archived.

But the **item deleting event receiver** doesn't get fired.

Event Reciever code

```
    public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       try
       {
           base.ItemDeleting(properties);
           SPWeb oWeb = properties.Web;
           SPListItem spLI = properties.ListItem;
           SPList oList = oWeb.GetList("mylist");
           string fileName = spLI.Name;
           string userID = string.Empty;
           if (oList != null)
           {
               SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
               query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ReportName\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ReportStatus\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">COMPLETED</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
               query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"UserID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ReportStatus\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ReportName\" />";
               query.RowLimit = Constants.CAML_QUERY_ROW_LIMIT;
               query.ViewAttributes = Constants.CAML_QUERY_VIEW_ATTRIBUTES_ALL;
               SPListItemCollection allfiles = reportInfoList.GetItems(query);
               if (allfiles != null)
               {
                   if (allfiles.Count > 0)
                   {
                       foreach (SPListItem spReportInfoItem in allfiles)
                       {
                           userID = spReportInfoItem["UserID"].ToString();
                           spReportInfoItem["Status] = "Archived";
                           spReportInfoItem.SystemUpdate();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception expException)
       {
        throw expException;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Is there any code you can show here? There doesn't seem to be much for readers to go on at present. If there is no code it is probably not a programming question, in which case it is off-topic here. You can ask the question on _Super User_, but please refrain from asking volunteers for urgency - if you need a speedy and guaranteed response, hire someone.

Comment: I am sorry for the "urgency part".

Comment: I have pasted my event reciever code, This doesnt get fired when the Information managment rention gets applied to my document library "mylist"

Comment: OK, much better. I don't know this technology, but the empty `catch()` looks worrying - should you not log/echo here? If you have a problem this code will hide it.

Comment: actually i am logging the catch just that i put this code an edited those parts. The issue isn't catch for me :(

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of google I figured out that a SystemUpdate() which does not fire events.
And the retention policy deletes from the list is a SystemUpdate() hence my event receiver doesn't get fired.
So I changed my code accordingly.